# Read table current Read/Write Capacity Units consumed DynamoDB

Tags: php, amazon-dynamodb

Is there any ways to read the Read/Write Capacity Units consumed of DynamoDB table?

I tried describeTable, but it only returns me Provisioned Read/Write Capacity Units. I hope i can get current Read/Write Capacity Units consumed of certain table.

Be more specific, I am writing my own monitor to check DynamoDB table capacity by php. if the capacity is high, i will do something. i do not want use CloudWatch Alarms. Is there any other ways to get Read/Write Capacity Units consumed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not part of the DynamoDB API.

What you want to do is use [AWS CloudWatch](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/service-cloudwatch.html) to get the metrics about current throughput (ConsumedReadCapacityUnits / ConsumedWriteCapacityUnits)

You can also view this data on [AWS DynamoDB Console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/home).

Comment: Thanks! I can get these data from CloudWatch API now. DynamoDB API do not have these interface.

Answer (score 0):

By default while creating a table, read/write capacity is 5. You can change that by giving parameter while creating table itself.

To check and monotor, the Read/Write Capacity Units consumption, you dont need to write own monitor. Just go to cosole of particular amazon dynamo db table, ther will be an option for set alaram. Actually amazon will take care of everything!

Answer (score 0):

Knowing the point-in-time consumed capacity or keeping a running total of consumed capacity is not all that useful. Amazon CloudWatch is the best way to track consumed capacity, because it can trigger alarms when you are consistently consuming capacity above the configured threshold.

However, DynamoDB does return the amount of consumed capacity for a given request in the response of that request. For example, see the [PHP API docs for `putItem()`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Aws.DynamoDb.DynamoDbClient.html#_putItem), as well as the corresponding [service API documentation for `PutItem`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_PutItem.html).